# Javascript how to trigger ajax call after a function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phonegap

Iam developing an application using Phonegap, everything is going fine but I want an ajax to be triggered after i get the qr code value from another function at the same page, is there a way to trigger it right after theuser gets the scan value? the code is a bit messy...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
 `var uemail = localStorage.getItem("semail"); 
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = uemail;`

      var dataString = "email=" + email + "&secode=" + value + "&insert=";
            var h = localStorage.getItem("secode");
        $("#conf").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://example.com/auth.php?email="+uemail+"&secode="+h+"",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                     $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {

                        if (data == "success") {

                             alert("DONNNEEE");
                        } else if (data == "error") {

                        alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
                  });
                   });

      function logoutck() {
    var r = confirm("هل انت واثق من ذلك؟");
    if (r) {
       window.location.href = 'login.html'
    }
}

    function scan()
            {
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                    function (result) {
                        if(!result.cancelled)
                        {

                            if(result.format == "QR_CODE")
                            {
                             var value = result.text;
                            localStorage.setItem("secode", value);
                               var h = localStorage.getItem("secode");
                               alert(h);
                            }
                        } else{
                        alert("U CANCELLED IT");
                        }
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                    }
               );
               }


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="loading">

</div>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
        <h1 class="title">EasyQ</h1>
        <a class="button button-clear" onclick="logoutck();">خروج</a>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container">




    <p style="text-align: right;">:انت مسجل دخولك ك</p>

  <div align="right"><span class="badge" align="right" dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" id="x"></span></div>
  <br>

 <a target="_blank" href="javascript:scan();" style="text-decoration: none"><button>Scan</button></a>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <button id="conf">confirmo</button>
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var uemail = localStorage.getItem("semail");
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = uemail;

      var dataString = "email=" + email + "&secode=" + value + "&insert=";
            var h = localStorage.getItem("secode");
        $("#conf").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://easyq.hol.es/easyqappfiles/qrauth.php?email="+uemail+"&secode="+h+"",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                     $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {

                        if (data == "success") {

                             alert("DONNNEEE");
                        } else if (data == "error") {

                        alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
                  });
                   });


</script>
```

Comment: make another ajax call in success?

Comment: @Silencer310 No... Look at the qr code javascript .. do u see the line if(result.format== "QR_CODE") I want to do an ajax call in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your ajax call as a function and call it when you need it.

```
function ajaxCall(){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(){
        // do something
    }
  });
}
```

And then

```
if(result.format == "QR_CODE") {
  ajaxCall();
}
```

You can also pass parameter to the function if needed

Comment: Thanks alot, im going to try it later 

Comment: it didn't work.. i did ajaxCall() and i put it after that as u said... still same.. it scans and when it finishes no ajax is called

Comment: does your other ajax call work? And are you sure the (result.format == "QR_CODE") is True at some point? Try printing something to the console in the ajaxCall() and see if that prints out

Comment: The (result.format... is a phonegap plugin it works 100% fine.. but the ajaxCall() im not sure that the original ajax call is working tho.. i assigned it to do on a button click but it doesnt work .. why??

Comment: Then your're problem is your Ajax isn't working. Did you correctly link the file in your styles? And the jquery.js ? Please post your HTML code

Comment: Yes i linked jquery and the file is hosted i linked it right but i want to make sure.. is this right?                  http://example.com/auth.php?email="+email +"&s="+s +"

Comment: First, check the console if it gives you an error. There are many places in the code that could be giving an error. For example, you defined "var uemail", but in datastring, you use the variable "email". What is email here?

Comment: Yeaah thats a point.. But im new to javascript can u please just tell me how to check thr console?

Comment: press ctrl+shift+J on your web page

Comment: you said you assigned ajax to your button and it doesn't work right? probably throws an error in the console

Comment: i will check it out soon ill be back :)

Comment: so what was the problem?

Comment: Actually idk  i just did that ajaxCall() u told me and i removed couple of functions then voila

Comment: great, so if my answer helped you, could you please accept it? :)